# Why am I getting a '$' is not defined when running an AJAX query?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

Possibly a dumb question, but I have a page where I'm trying to load list data into a customer table to display as a front-end.  I'm retrieving this list from a SharePoint list using an AJAX call in a Javascript function, however when I'm using this function my console returns a `SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined` error.  Previously, I've used an AJAX call successfully using very similar code, but to return a single item from the list using the list ID to search for a specific item, and I've run the query successfully directly from the URL that returns the data I'm after - I'm just not sure what's happening with this one.

```
function getIncidents(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "SharepointURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Incident List')/items?$select=Title,Id,Priority,IncidentStart,IncidentStatus,IncidentTitle,UpdateResolution",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
  success: function (data) {
   var dResponse = data.d.results;
   var results = document.getElementById('Results');
   results.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Incident<br>Reference</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td>Priority</td><td style='width:20px;'></td><td>Start Time</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Issue</td><td style='width:20px'></td><td style='width:170px'>Latest Update</td><td style='width:20px'></td></tr>";
   for(var obj in dResponse){
    results.innerHTML += "<tr style='font-size:10pt'><td>"+dResponse[obj].Title + "</td><td></td><td>" + dResponse[obj].Priority + "</td><td></td><td>" + dResponse[obj].IncidentStart + "</td><td></td><td>" + dResponse[obj].IncidentTitle + "</td><td></td><td>" + dResponse[obj].UpdateResolution + "</td></tr>";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Previous example where I have this call working:

```
function getIncident() {
    var listName="Incident List";
    var incidentID = $("#incidentReference").val();
    if(incidentID!=""){
        $.ajax({
            url: "SharepointURL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Incident List')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + incidentID + "'&$select=Title,Id,SystemOrService,Priority,IncidentStatus,IncidentTitle,UpdateResolution,IncidentStart,ImpactedArea,IncidentEnd",
            type: "GET",
            headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>0){
                    var item=data.d.results[0];
            $("#systemImpacted").val(item.SystemOrService);
            $("#incidentPriority").val(item.Priority);
                    $("#incidentState").val(item.IncidentStatus);
                    $("#incidentTitle").val(item.IncidentTitle);
                    $("#incidentUpdate").val(item.UpdateResolution);
            $("#startTime").val(item.IncidentStart);
            $("#impactedAreas").val(item.ImpactedArea.results);
            $("#endTime").val(item.IncidentEnd);

           updateImpact();
           getStartTime();
           getEndTime();
           actionsFormat();
                }                
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Incident Reference incorrect or not found");
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: All your code aside, are you properly adding jquery?

Comment: are you using jquery? what lib are you loading in for $?

Comment: add jquery at the top it should work

Comment: The ajax method you are trying to use is part of jQuery. The jQuery API is denoted by the dollar sign. Do you have jQuery installed?

Comment: Yep I have definitely asked a very dumb question - I just checked my library and I had a mistake there, thanks!

Comment: Always wait for jquery to load and use $(document).ready(function () {

// code

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery ($) is not yet loaded to the page. If you used it before, this means that loading is already setup, so you don't need to add more references to the jQuery.

In most of the cases, when you working with jQuery, you will subscribe on DOM event ready event and do your code there.

So, all you need is to find the

```
$(document).ready( ...
```

statement and insert your code there.

If you want to separate your code from already existed, you may write your own $(document).ready subscription.

If you will not find this $(document).ready function, you can search in html for the reference to the jQuery, and insert your script **after** it. But, than you need to be sure, that reference doesn't include async or defer attribute.

As mentioned in comments, if you decide to add your own subscription, you also need to place it after jQuery reference, because it will not work, if $ isn't available.

Comment: `$(document).ready` will not work before jQuery is loaded. That event is only useful for waiting until the DOM is fully loaded, or at least in state where it can be manipulated.

Comment: @Evert As far as author mentioned, that he already worked with jQuery, I assume that it subscription set in proper place. 
But this good point for clarification, thanks!